# How can I get greater than 1m position accuracy with android FusedLocationProviderClient?

Tags: java, android, location, google-geolocation

I'm trying to create an android app that gives accurate location (1m or less) indoors. It seems the recommended way is to use the 
[a FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient)

However the current horizontal accuracy I'm getting is between 5m and 15m for longitude and latitude while the vertical accuracy is often up to 50m out.

Not sure if it makes a difference but the the test device is an HTC U11?

I've updated google play service location **com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0**

I've included android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in my app manifest and `locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);` in the location request.

I've got some code in there which turns the GPS on.

```java
 mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(3 * 1000); // 3 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 3 seconds

new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });

locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();


                            Lat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
                            Longs.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
                            Acc.setText(String.format("%.2f", location.getAccuracy()));

                        if(location.hasAltitude()) {

                            Alt.setText(String.format("%.2f",location.getAltitude() - 108));
                            VAcc.setText(String.format("%.2f",location.getVerticalAccuracyMeters()));
                        }
                        else {
                            Alt.setText("Lost");
                            VAcc.setText("Lost");
                        }

                            SendToBackend(wayLatitude,wayLongitude, location);

                        if (!isContinue && mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

According to google it should be possible to get below 1m accuracy indoors. [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vywGgSrGODU).

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: There're lots of reasons which may affect accuracy: weather, environment, device, satellites state and probably some other reasons. And I'm afraid that you can't really do anything else to improve accuracy.

Comment: The Google IO video you link to refers to WiFi RTT or 802.11mc which is a part of WiFi 6. Your setup will need to support all of the requirements listed: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt , specifically your WiFi access point needs to supports the protocol.